# Adding Array into an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Assuming I have a group of string which has a delimiter of a character, how can i add this as an array in an array?

```
private fileTextHeaders = array();
public function addHeaders($longStringHeaders){

    $parts = explode("@", $longStringHeaders);

    foreach ($parts as $part){
        $this->fileTextHeaders[] = $part;
    }

    print_r($this->fileTextHeaders);    
}
```

I have the following code, but the result is

```
addHeaders("test@yes@no"); 
array ([0]=>test, [1]=>yes, [2]=no)
```

my goal is

```
array(
    array(test),
    array(yes),
    array(no)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($parts as $part){
    $this->fileTextHeaders[] = [$part];
}
```

Comment: ohh thats it? Thank you very much!